# VOW TREB how to get same property from archive files?

Tags: php, rets, phrets

I am using phprets to get VOW feed. Now I try to get the sold data from the archive file. I have access to get archive data from VOW TREB and download the files. 
But I don't know how to get the same listing detail from other archive files.

Comment: what do you meant by other archive files?

Comment: We can download files for every month.
if we make a database from all files then how I will check for a listing to sold history?
have any other way to check a listing sold history.

Comment: Is there any field called "Modification Timestamp" or something similar. If then that indicates the changes occured to same listings.